# What's the meaning of "cpu_intr" and "cpu_sintr" in ganglia

Tags: linux, ganglia

Where can I see these metrics of explanation？

cpu_ctxt, cpu_intr, cpu_sintr, cpu_aidle, cpu_steal

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that `cpu_ctxt` represents the number of context switches as reported by `/proc/stat` (see [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) or `vmstat` (`cs`field).

Also, `man top` reveals the meaning of the other metrics:

```
       us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
       sy, system  : time running kernel processes
       ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
       id, idle    : time spent in the kernel idle handler
       wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
       hi : time spent servicing hardware interrupts
       si : time spent servicing software interrupts
       st : time stolen from this vm by the hypervisor
```

where:

- cpu_intr maps to `hi`
- cpu_sintr maps to `si`
- cpu_aidle maps to `id`
- cpu_steal maps to `st`

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49111789/1753435) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/229427/what-does-cpu-aidle-mean-in-ganglia-reports) answer.