# What does 'sintr' mean (in Ganglia)?

Tags: cpu, ganglia

I have created the following view in Ganglia, showing `cpu_user` stats:

[image]

Can someone tell me what `Sintr` means? I was not able to find any information on Google or stackexchange websites.

Interestingly, I have two servers with identical hardware that I'm monitoring, but only one of them has the `Sintr` entry (which caught my eye).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found an answer hidden in some Ganglia dev mailing list...

From [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/ganglia/mailman/message/7178475/):

> I also added two specific metrics to Linux. cpu_intr and cpu_sintr
>   count the number of cycles spent on hard/soft interrupts.

Still wondering why it's only shown for one server and not for the other, but that's another story.